# Dynamic/changing last line in log file

Tags: python, logging

I have a logger, where I append a line for each downloaded file, because I need to monitor that.

But then I end up with log full of these. I would like a solution where when downloading 50.000 files from server, the last line would just change the count of the downloads finished and last file downloaded, like this:

```
[timestamp] Started downloading 50 000 files.
[timestamp] Downloaded 1002th file - filename.csv
[timestamp] <Error downloading this file> #show only when err ofc
[timestamp] Download finished.
```

This is not a terminal log, it is a log file, which I read actively with `tail -f`.

How can I make the line `Downloaded 1002th file - filename.csv` dynamic?

Comment: So in the end you would like your log file to contain 4 lines, not 50003?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to write whole file at once, after each download is complete, and truncate it before each such write. Otherwise you would have to work on rather low level, using
seek and tell function of python file object, which would be rather overkill (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) to just save few lines. In any solution such changes on file may not work properly with tail -f (because if file size does not change, tail may not update position in file; moreover if you reopen file in python, file descriptor will change and you may have to use tail -F ). Maybe it would be enough to use `watch cat`?

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to modify the log file is:

1. Very hard, as you're trying to modify it while continuously writing it from Python:

   1. If you'll do it from an external program, you'll have 2 writers on the same file section and it can cause big issues.
   2. If you'll do it from Python, you won't actually be able to use the logging module, as you'd need to start creating custom file handlers and flags.
   3. You'll cause issues with `tail -F` actually reading this.
2. Discouraged. The log is a log, you shouldn't go in random sections and modify them.

If you wish to easily monitor this, you have multiple different solutions:

- Write the "successfully downloaded file" using `logging.debug` instead of `logging.info`. Then monitor on `logging.INFO` level. I believe this is the best course of action. You can even write the `debug` to one log and `info` to another, and monitor the info.
- Send a "successfully downloaded 10/100/1000 files". That'll batch the `logging.info` rows.
- Use any type of external monitoring. More of a custom solution, a bit out of scope for the question.

Comment: Thanks, yeah this is my solution right now with the logger. I guess it makes sense, i will just have to be ok with grep for now to filter out the tail -f output. It is true that another process might log something and the 'dynamic' line will not be last, which would make it indeed bad practice to modify that. I think ```tail -f | grep -v 'not wanted'``` will do.